# Mocking method with callback param

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, mockery

I am trying to mock this method:

```
$transformer = $this->transformerFactory->createProductTransformer($product, function (ProductInterface $product) use ($discount) {
    $product->setDiscount($discount);
});
```

It accepts callback parameter as a second argument and I don't know how to mock it.

I am using Mockery so that would look like that:

```
$this->transformerFactoryMock
    ->shouldReceive('createProductTransformer')
    ->with(???) // here!
```

If I pass the same callback to the with() method, the instances does not match.
I don't mind using PHPUnit mocking if Mockery doesn't support that.

Answer (score 4):

If you need check exactly that callback is called then it is not possible as each `\Closure` instance is unique and inside your tested method you created new one.

But you can do next:

1) validate dynamic args for type

```
// Assume in test case you have these mock/stub
$discount;
$product;

$transformerFactoryMock = \Mockery::mock('TransformerFactory')
    ->shouldReceive('createProductTransformer')
    ->with($product, \Mockery::type(\Closure::class))
```

2) check any hidden args (created before call mocked method inside your testing method)

```
$transformerFactoryMock = \Mockery::mock('TransformerFactory')
    ->shouldReceive('createProductTransformer')
    ->with(function(...$args) use ($product) {
        // check any args
    })
```

3) finally, fake result using passed callback to mocked method

```
// then mock will be
$transformerFactoryMock = \Mockery::mock('TransformerFactory')
    ->shouldReceive('createProductTransformer')
    ->andReturnUsing(function($closure) {
        // execute closure
        $closure();

        // any logic to fake return
        return;
    })
```

Check doc of [mockery complex argument matching](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/cookbook/mockery_on.html) and [declaring return value](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/expectations.html#declaring-return-value-expectations)

Answer (score 1):

If the "same callback" means identical code, then it's not the same callback for PHP and so Mockery will not accept it.

```
var_dump(function () {} === function () {}); // false
$func = function () {};
var_dump($func === $func); // true
```

To check callback type you can use mockery::type method (with argument 'closure') and for more precise checking there is mockery::on. https://github.com/padraic/mockery#argument-validation

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to tell exactly what you're trying to do in your test file from the snippet you pasted, but you can mock Closures and their params. Here's a quick/dirty/untested example that is a best guess at what you're trying to accomplish:

```
class Transformer {

    protected transformerFactory;

    public function __construct($factory) {
        $this->transformerFactory = $factor;
    }

    public function doSomething(Discount $discount, ProductInterface $product) {

        return $this->transformerFactory->createProductTransformer($product, function($product) use ($discount) {
            $product->setDiscount($discount);
        });
    }

}


class TransformerTest {

    protected function makeTransformerWithFakeFactory()
    {
        $fakeFactory = \Mockery::mock('TransformerFactory');

        $transformer = new Transformer($fakeFactory);

        return array($tranformer, $fakeFactory);
    }

    protected function fakeDiscount()
    {
        return \Mockery::mock('Discount');
    }

    protected function fakeProduct()
    {
        return \Mocker::mock('ProductInterface');
    }

            // first let's test to make sure that the factory's correct method is called with correct parameters
    function test_doSomething_WhenPassedProduct_CallsCreateProductTransformerOnFactoryWithProductAndClosure()
    {
        list($transformer, $mockFactory) = $this->makeTransformerWithFakeFactory();
        $fakeDiscount = $this->fakeDiscount();
        $fakeProduct = $this->fakeProduct();

        $mockFactory->shouldReceive('createProductTransformer')->once()->with($fakeProduct, \Mockery::type('Closure'));

        $transfomer->doSomething($fakeDiscount, $fakeProduct);
    }

            // now, let's test to make sure that the $discount within the closure is called with the right method and params
        function test_doSomething_createProductTransformerCalledWithProductAndClosure_CallsSetDiscountOnProductWithDiscount()
    {
        list($transformer, $stubFactory) = $this->makeTransfomerWithFakeFactory();
        $fakeDiscount = $this->fakeDiscount();
        $mockProduct = $this->fakeProduct();
        $stubFactory->shouldReceive('createProductTransfomer')->passthru();

        $mockProduct->shouldReceive('setDiscount')->once()->with($fakeDiscount);

        $transfomer->doSomething($fakeDiscount, $mockProduct);
    }

            // now lets make sure that doSomething returns what the call to factory's createProductTransformer method returns
    function test_doSomething_createProductTransformerCalledWithProductAndClosureReturnsValue_ReturnsSameValue()
    {
        list($transformer, $stubFactory) = $this->makeTransfomerWithFakeFactory();
        $fakeDiscount = $this->fakeDiscount();
        $fakeProduct = $this->fakeProduct();
        $stubFactory->shouldReceive('createProductTransfomer')->andReturn('transformed result');

        $result = $transfomer->doSomething($fakeDiscount, $fakeProduct);

        $this->assertEquals('transformed result', $result);
    }

}
```